# Issues installing Docker on RHEL 7 Linux Server

Tags: rhel, docker

I have been constantly running into this issue more and more lately, and finally need some assistance because I'm completely stuck.

I just got access to a RHEL EC2 Linux server and I am just simply trying to install Docker. This process has been extremely painful lately. Tons of 404 HTTP Not Found errors when trying to follow the processes mentioned online

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html, you can just simply run one of the following two commands:

- sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
- sudo yum install docker

However, neither one of these comands work, as shown in the output below:

```
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]# sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]# yum install docker
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, search-disabled-repos
No package docker available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]#
```

Here is a list of things I've tried to do :

***First Attempt*** (RE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918841/how-to-install-docker-on-amazon-linux2)

The second answer proposed in that you can just run the following:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum -y install docker
```

However, that doesn't work either, as shown in the output below:

```
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]# yum update -y
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, search-disabled-repos
No packages marked for update
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]# yum -y install docker
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, search-disabled-repos
No package docker available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]#
```

***Second Attempt***: Installing via `get.docker.com`

When running `curl https://get.docker.com | bash`, that doesn't work either

[image]

***Third Attempt***: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-docker-ce-on-rhel-7-linux/

Part of this article suggests running the following two commands:

```
sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
```

However, that doesn't work either:

```
# yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

https://download.docker.com/linux/rhel/7/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article 

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.



 One of the configured repositories failed (Docker CE Stable - x86_64),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=docker-ce-stable ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable docker-ce-stable
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=docker-ce-stable

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=docker-ce-stable.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from docker-ce-stable: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://download.docker.com/linux/rhel/7/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

Here's the output of my `cat /etc/os-release` command

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It seems nearly impossible to install docker at this point.

Comment: According to https://connect.redhat.com/resources/running-containerized-docker-applications-rhel-instance-amazon-ami, you need to activate your Redhat subscription and enable a few additional repos before `yum install docker`.

Comment: I had this same experience. Thanks for explaining so well. It was very painful to try this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ with this file:

https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

The one you downloaded only works if you are running s390x systems.  Docker is kinda dumb about how they structure their yum repos and this confuses people all the time.

Proof:  look at the directories in the [rhel/7 directory](https://download.docker.com/linux/rhel/7) compared to the ones in the [centos/7 directory](https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7).  The rhel directory only contains s390x and source, and the CentOS one has an x86_64 directory with the packages and repo metadata.

Comment: I think this was on purpose to get people to use the paid version of things on rhel. But either way, this still did not work for me, there was an error about signatures.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found

Mean `amazon-linux-extras` isn't installed, you need to install it:

```
sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
```

Docker is available in Extras:

> [Docker is only in extras](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/amazon-linux-2/release-notes/)

> The package for Docker is only available through extras and is enabled by default. When new versions of Docker are released, support will be provided only for the most current stable packages.

To install docker:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
sudo service docker start
sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
```

[Amazon : Installing Docker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html#install_docker)

Comment: this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Issues installing Docker on RHEL 7 Linux Server

FYI, there is currently a guide for this:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html-single/getting_started_with_containers/index#getting_docker_in_rhel_7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and days of pain trying to figure this out. My answer is to not use Docker on RHEL or not use RHEL. Both of these are sub-optimal but it really seems like RHEL wants you to use openshift and get away from Docker completely.

Answer (score 0):

create an `/etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo` having

```
[docker]
name=docker
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
baseurl=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable
```

**note, there seemed to be no valid RHEL docker repo, it is the centos docker repo that works**

I did not detail the extra repo's to support nvidia docker (see below) but those instructions published on nvidia's docker site were valid.

The following then works for me, in RHEL 7.9 x86-64

```
yum install
 containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
 docker-ce-20.10.5-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
 docker-ce-cli-20.10.5-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
 docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.5-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
 libnvidia-container1-1.3.3-1.x86_64.rpm
 libnvidia-container-tools-1.3.3-1.x86_64.rpm
 nvidia-container-runtime-3.4.2-1.x86_64.rpm
 nvidia-container-toolkit-1.4.2-2.x86_64.rpm
 nvidia-docker2-2.5.0-1.noarch.rpm

systemctl --now enable docker
systemctl restart docker
systemctl status docker
docker -v
  Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
```

These are the named gpg keys that were available

```
gpgkey-docker-ce-centos
gpgkey-docker-ce-rhel
gpgkey-libnvidia-container
gpgkey-nvidia-container-runtime
gpgkey-nvidia-docker
```

Docker with Nvidia can work in RHEL 7.9.